# mysql union of calculated rows

Tags: mysql

```
     Cat_name                  Date           Channel             Sales

    Category                2015-07-16       Direct         32445289
    Exclusives_cat         2015-07-16        DIRECT         11844679
    NOnExclusives_cat       2015-07-16       DIRECT         32445289-11844679
```

Need suggestion for calculating NOnExclusives_cat in same format.

already have category and Exclusives_cat level data.

Comment: Could you please add your table description and query that you used?

Comment: put table structure http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/

Comment: What did you do for this

Comment: not sure,use case statement  or not..